# Send signal from one winforms application to another

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a C# Win forms application, it has UI and optionally take command line argument to execute some process. I have a new request where an external application will provide command line argument and my application need to provide progress status to the external application. I want to make minimum change to my application for this task.

For example, my application launch by external program as below:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();        
startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\ProgramFolder\MyProgram.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = @"C:\arguments.txt";
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

While my application running, it need to send information like, account in progress, account processed, all accounts completed, etc signal.

Should my application write progress status to a predefined folder then external application use file watcher to monitor new files and get status? My research shows another option named pipes, which new to me but hopefully can manage it. Is there any other alternative approach?

Comment: You can use WCF. One application will be the host and one will be the client. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758(v=vs.110).aspx) for details.

Comment: Your launcher/monitor appmication can read the console output and error streams.

Comment: there are many kinds of IPC for you, however your idea is very OK to me.

Comment: WCF, Remoting, named pipes, sockets, memory mapped files, plain files.  Pick one.  And carefully think about what's going to happen when one of the processes crashes with an unhandled exception, pretty hard to deal with.  In itself a very good reason to use a class library instead of a separate process.

Comment: have you use Control.WndProc. you can transfer message between various application using it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you all for your response, I will proceed to file watcher approach.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late to give you any advice...but it can be useful for someone else.

To send informations between two or more different procceses, you can use MMFs,
"Memory Mapped File" 
 What is? : you can find a good description [by clicking Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file)

I'm sorry if i can't be accurate enough but i'm still studying the argument
...
you can use the MemoryMappedFile class from C# using [System.IO:MemoryMappedFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.io.memorymappedfiles?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: It's not the best idea to put links to get more description. They can change or just expire.